# How do I release this allocation?

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, delegates

I got this code off another thread on here and it works perfectly, but it leaks, and I don't know how to release it.  I have tried adding "autorelease" statements to the GoToNext alloc line.  It didnt help.  Anyone know how to properly handle this?

```
webView.delegate = [[GoToNext alloc] initWithTarget:self andNext:@selector(loadUpdateGraph)]; //leak
```

This is the GoToNext code:

.h

```
    @interface GoToNext : NSObject <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    id __weak target;
    SEL next;
}
-(id)initWithTarget:(id)target andNext:(SEL)next;
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "GoToNext.h"


@implementation GoToNext
-(id)initWithTarget:(id)_target andNext:(SEL)_next {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        target = _target;
        next = _next;
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [target performSelector:next];
}
@end
```

Comment: for every init, don't you have to release it yourself?  so shouldn't there be a `self = [[super init] autorelease];`?  I'm just getting into Xcode myself, so I might be very wrong!

Comment: I just tried that, it causes a Zombie error thing and crashes the app. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an instance of `GoToNext` using `alloc`, that instance has a retain count of 1.  Somewhere in your app you must release this instance before you lose your only reference to it (which in this case is the `delegate` property of `webView`).  The `delegate` property of a `UIWebView` uses `assign` semantics, so assigning your instance of `GoToNext` to that property does not retain it.  This means that you cannot `release` or `autorelease` it while it is still the delegate of `webView` or `webView.delegate` will point to deallocated memory.

If you're sure you're only setting `webView.delegate` once in the lifecycle of the class containing this code, you can get by with just put `[webView.delegate release]` in the `dealloc` method of that class.  If you're setting it more than once, you might try creating a method like:

```
-(void)setWebViewDelegate:(id)delegate {
    if (webView.delegate) {
        [webView.delegate release];
    }
    webView.delegate = delegate;
}
```

And using that method to set `webView`'s delegate.  There are other ways to handle this situation, but I think this method will probably require the fewest changes to your code.

Of course, in my opinion the best solution of all is to just [convert the application to ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) and never have to worry about this kind of thing again.

Comment: Ohhhh thats why I had errors.  I was trying to release it while it was still the current delegate.  I used that method and called it every time I changed delegate and it worked perfectly!